# How to know which package is being used when two packages with same name are installed at different location?

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed Hokuyo_node deprecated version from github. I already have Hokuyo_node installed while installing ROS. Now, when I use `rosun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node`, how do I make sure which package is being used?

thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269470/how-to-know-which-package-is-being-used-when-two-packages-with-same-name-are-installed-at-different-location?/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2017-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rospack find hokuyo_node` will tell you which package path it's using. The directories that ROS tools use to search for packages are listed in `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, which is typically set by the `setup.bash` file in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2017-08-23**:
thanks, got it.